# How to find and replace a property in a property file using shell script?

Tags: shell

My property file has property WLS_Home={Path to server}
How to replace this with another path which i have in a script variable ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed:

```
sed '/^WLS_Home=/s@=.*$@='"$new_path"@g
```

Where new_path is the variable containing the new path.  You will not want to use `/` as the delimiter in `sed`, since that is likely to appear in the path.  You can overwrite the original file using shell redirections (ie `sed ... file > tmp-file && mv tmp-file file`), or `-i` if your `sed` supports that non-standard feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

new_path="/the/new/path"
sed -i "s%WLS_Home=.*%WLS_Home=$new_path%g" my_properties.file
```

Do not use `/` as your `sed` separators, or this going to throw some errors at you since you have some in your paths.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sed`.

`sed -i 's/Path_to_server/new_path_to_server/g' file`